# Using Method to Read/Write value in Textbox in C#

Tags: c#

I have **form1** and **class1**.
I would like to use a method to read/write the text in a textbox in form1 at class1. 
This is the segment of the program. I currently able to interact between those two. The only problem is I do not how to convert the string to a form which can be read.

In **form1**:

```
public string readTxt(string txtbox_name) 
{
string txtbox_val;
txtbox_val = (txtbox_name).Text; //problem here
return txtbox_val;
} 

public void writeTxt(string txtbox_name,string txtbox_val)
{
    (txtbox_name).Text = txtbox_val; //problem here
}
```

For example i need to read/write value in textbox1.

In **class1**:

```
string text1 = (readTxt(textbox1)); //for get the text in textbox1
string text2 = "Hello"
writeTxt(textbox1,text2); //for overwrite the text in textbox1 to "Hello"
```

Sorry for the question quite confusing due to not good in ask question.

Comment: Can you explain the use case of what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Use events. c# is event driven language. You dont need any method to get text on the text box, in your class just write txtbox_name.Text. It will return the text on your text box. you can assign text in to variable to like this var text= txtbox_name.Text. if you need to log in console when user is on typing just use keyup event in text box.

Comment: TextBox and Console. What's that for a funny app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For winforms, you could use [Control.ControlCollection.Find(String, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Find_System_String_System_Boolean_)

> Searches for controls by their Name property and builds an array of
> all the controls that match.

and [Enumerable.OfType(IEnumerable)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8)

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

```
public string ReadText(string txtbox_name) 
{
    // insert false if you expect not to be in a sub control
    return Controls.Find(txtbox_name,true) 
                  .OfType<TextBox>()
                  .FirstOrDefault()?.Text
}
```

However I fear your problem is actually, how can I get text from my TextBox.

```
var text = MyControl.Text;
```

**Update**

> How about if I would like to write into Textbox.

```
var textBox = Controls.Find(txtbox_name,true) 
                      .OfType<TextBox>()
                      .FirstOrDefault();

if(textBox != null)
textBox.Text = "yehaa";
```

**Clarification**

The difference between calling `Find`, and the other approaches, is that if your `Textbox` is buried in a `Panel` or other *SubControls* the other approaches won't find it. Other than that, they are exactly the same. `Find` works on the second parameter flag, and I'd an option to search *subcontrols*

> `searchAllChildren`
>
> true to search all child controls; otherwise, false.

Comment: How about if i would like to write into Textbox.

Comment: @RoyceAng updated.

Answer (score 3):

You could Search for all TextBox with the name and get the Text using the [Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=netframework-4.8) Property.
For Example,

```
public string ReadText(string txtbox_name)
{
   return Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Single(x => x.Equals(txtbox_name)).Text;
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds. Almost identical code.